# Accessing attribute depending on a state of another object

Tags: python

I want to access an objects attribute depending on a state of another object.

```
class Action(IntEnum):
    idle = 0
    attack = 1

class UnitAnimations:
    def __init__(self, idle_list, attack_list):
        self.idle = idle_list
        self.attack = attack_list
        self.image = idle_list[0]


class Unit:
    def __init(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.action = Action.idle
        self.animations = UnitAnimations(idle_list, attack_list)

        def update(self):
            frame_index = 0
            # here I want to set appropriate image based on self.action value  
            # pseudocode
            self.animations.image = self.animations{self.action.name}[frame_index]
```

depending on the Unit.action value I want to set the Unit.animations.image to the appropriate list (UnitAnimations.idle or UnitAnimations.attack) how can I implement that behavior
?

Comment: That's `getattr(self.animations, self.action.name)`.

Comment: There's no need for those to be two separate classes.  Just have one class called "Action".  When you change the action state, it can automatically change the image.